# Sort Date in a specific format in EXTJS

Tags: javascript, sorting, datetime, extjs

I have a Date column in a Ext JS grid with its display format like: `"Jan 22,2014 08:43:21"`.
My problem is how to sort with this format, currently it is sorted follow String format.

Example, when I have 2 rows with corresponding values are:

```
"Jan 22,2014 08:43:21" 
"Nov 20,2013 08:43:21"
```

My expectation after sorting ASC is that the second row will be showed first, cause 20/11/2013 is before 22/01/2014, but it is sorting by String format, so the result is incorrect.

Could you please help me on this?
Thank you very much.

Comment: Use 'remote' sort. Sort data on server

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing that is to use sorterFn, fiddle here: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/2u7